# GA - Register a conversion without redirecting to the parameter used in the goog_report_conversion function

Tags: google-analytics, click-tracking

I have a form which redirects to a third party site. My client wishes to register a conversion when this form is submitted.

I've used the click tracking script as described by Google [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6331304?hl=en-GB).

My form's submit button then has the following code:

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT &gt;"  onclick="goog_report_conversion('http://www.example.com/conversion')"  />
```

My assumption was that this would work the same as if someone had landed on http://www.example.com/conversion, without actually going to that page, and thus my client could configure his GA to register hitting that URL as a conversion.

I assumed that http://www.example.com/conversion didn't actually need to exist, but I created it as a blank page to be on the safe side.

However, when this onclick event is triggered, it redirects to http://www.example.com/conversion rather than submitting the form (in Chrome, anyway).

The part of the tracking code causing this seems to be the following:

```
var opt = new Object();
      opt.onload_callback = function() {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
      }
```

Is this because I have misunderstood what goog_report_conversion does, and as such should I be looking at a different way to report a click as a conversion?  Or is there a configuration option in GA that says to redirect or not redirect to goog_report_conversion's parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the conversion is being tracked via an onclick, rather than an onsubmit?

Comment: To be honest, that's just because the Google example was onclick and I was sticking to that as much as possible.  The order the events loads is the same with either call, though.

Answer (score -1):

Adding return false; should prevent the link in the onclick from being followed.
eg

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT &gt;"  onclick="goog_report_conversion('http://www.example.com/conversion'); return false;"  />
```

Comment: That would stop the form being submitted, but would make no difference to how goog_report_conversion runs.